# Ember: Even after refresh some attributes in the model are not changed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, model-view-controller, ember.js

I am new to EmberJS, and facing problem with model data updation

**Controller** :

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
queryParams: ['jobid'],
jobid: null,
currentCount: null,

actions: {
 onOffToggle(e) {
  var isChanged = this.get('model.b.isChanged');
  this.set('model.b.enable', e.target.checked);
  this.set('model.b.isChanged', !isChanged);
  console.log(this.get('model.b.isChanged'))
},
iterationCountChange() {
  var currentCount = this.get('currentCount');
  var isCountChanged =
      (currentCount != this.get('model.b.count')) ? true : false;
  this.set('model.b.isCountChanged', isCountChanged);
}
}});
```

**Route:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

beforeModel: function (transition) {
this.jobid = transition.queryParams.jobid;
},
model(){
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    a:   this.store.queryRecord('a', {jobid: this.get("jobid")}),
    b: this.store.queryRecord('b', {id: this.get("jobid")})
 });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model)
controller.set('currentCount', model.b.get('iterationCount'))
},

actions: {
 paramChange(a, b)
  Ember.$.ajax({
    url: "/rest/test",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
       b: b,
       a: a
     })
   }).then(response => {
    this.refresh();
  })
},
error(error, transition) {
  if (error.errors[0].status == 404) {
    return this.transitionTo('not-found', { queryParams: {'previous': window.location.href}});
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Here in controller I am keeping track if some value have changed, and if they have changed then update the flag related to their change, these flags like `isChanged` and `isCountChanged` are the part of the model's data, after user cliks submit button , `paramChange`
 action is called and then a post call is made to update the db for respective property changes, and then `this.refresh()` is called to render the latest model data.

But the problem is, once `isChanged` and/or `isCountChanged` are changed from their default value, then they don't reset to the new value present in the model data, e.g. after `refresh` the value to both these flags should be reset to false but it comes always true, I checked the value in the `setUpController` hook for the values of these flags and it confirms to true.

According to me it has something to with the controller, since any value which is used in controller once is not resetting to new value coming after `refresh`.

Kindly help I am spent a lot of time in this and got nothing till now, do inform if any extra information is required.

Ember version: 2.6

Comment: Even the value of `currentCount` is not resetting, which is not updated in backend, all this is leading to update the backed as the flags for tracking updation are always true once a modification is made.

Comment: In the model hook , I must be getting updated as in the Inspect the API call response shows the new data is received, I don't know to print the model details in model hook.

Comment: controllers are singletons so their state is not reset during your application lifecycle. If you want this use a component or clean up yourself in `setupController`.

Comment: How using a component would help? Also it is okay to set the variables of controller to set, but my biggest concern is that why my model attributes are not refreshing.

Comment: How are you initializing `isChanged` and `isCountChanged`? You claim these "are the part of the model's data". Are you storing these values in the database? If you set a `debugger` in the `setupController`, is your model data as you expect it? What is `model.tunein`?

Comment: Yes `isChanged` and `isCountChanged` is returned by my rest API as `false` always. Also on setting debugger in `setUpController` the value of `isChanged` and `isCountChanged` is not as expected, and `model.tunein` was a editing mistake, kindly ignore that.

Comment: what version of Ember Data and Ember are you using?

Comment: updated the post with Ember version.

Answer (score 0):

From docs,

> Refresh the model on this route and any child routes, firing the
>   beforeModel, model, and afterModel hooks in a similar fashion to how
>   routes are entered when transitioning in from other route. The current
>   route params (e.g. article_id) will be passed in to the respective
>   model hooks, and if a different model is returned, setupController and
>   associated route hooks will re-fire as well.

So, if your model data doesn't change, `setupController()` is not called. My approach is to have a custom method to update controller with model data. Then, I call this method from `model()` hook (for `this.refresh()`) and from `setupController()`.

```
model() {
  return this.store.query(....).then(data => this.updateControllerData(data));
}

setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(...arguments);

  this.updateControllerData(data);
}

updateControllerData(data = {}) {
  if (!this.controller) {
    return;
  }

  this.controller.setProperties(data);
}
```

Note that if `setupController()` is not fired, the controller data is always updated.